# NSInvalidArgumentException – App terminates while i'm trying to copy a captured video to documents folder

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller, video-processing

I'd like to try the wisdom of the crowds..because i'm frustrated right now.
Thanks in advance.

So here is my code:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)ipc didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
```

NSLog(@"info: %@",info);

NSString *newFilename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.mov", 
        [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"], 
        [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (long)[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]]];

NSLog(@"newFilename: %@",newFilename);

NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

NSError *err;
  if ([filemgr copyItemAtPath:[info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL"] toPath:newFilename error:&err] == YES)
        NSLog (@"Move successful");
 else
        NSLog (@"Move failed");

and this is the log:

```
 2010-05-16 18:19:01.975 erlkoenig[7099:307] info: {
    UIImagePickerControllerMediaType = "public.movie";
    UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL = "file://localhost/private/var/mobile/Applications/BE25F9B5-2D08-4B59-8B62-D04DF7BB7E5B/tmp/-Tmp-/capture-T0x108cb0.tmp.8M81HU/capturedvideo.MOV";
   }
newFilename: /var/mobile/Applications/BE25F9B5-2D08-4B59-8B62-D04DF7BB7E5B/Documents/1274026741.mov

[NSURL fileSystemRepresentation]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1c1f90
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSURL fileSystemRepresentation]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1c1f90
```

Comment: `[NSURL fileSystemRepresentation]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1c1f90`

Which means that somewhere in your code, you're trying to run `fileSystemRepresentation` on an instance of `NSURL`, but this selector/method doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

I can follow you logic but have one fundamental issue: **this is not how you save video**.

Please see a rough example below without the relevant error checking.

```
(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info

{

    .... code here .....

    NSString* videoURL= [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

    //remember to test that the video is compatible for saving to the photos album

    UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(videoURL, self, @selector(video:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);

    .... code here .....

}
```

Comment: Please flag this as the correct answer: this place is give and take.

Comment: The original poster isn't trying to save the file to the photo album, they are trying to save it to their app's documents folder. Your response is an answer, not the correct answer.